# Dwa failed to produce path in free space

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all. I found a bug for [dwa local planner](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/indigo-devel/dwa_local_planner). When the goal is in the -x and -y direction  with respect to robot's current pose, the robot moves really slowly, even stop.

It outputs **"The dwa local planner failed to find a valid plan, cost functions discarded all candidates. This can mean there is an obstacle too close to the robot".** This information is generated from [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/dwa_local_planner/src/dwa_planner_ros.cpp#L216) when the cost of computed path is smaller than zero.

Obviously, we can see that there is no obstacle around the robot at that time.  This case can be repeated as long as we want.
[image: toal_cost]

The parameters are listed as follows:

```
DWAPlannerROS:

# Robot Configuration Parameters - Kobuki
  max_vel_x: 0.3  # 0.55
  min_vel_x: 0.0 

  max_vel_y: 0.0  # diff drive robot
  min_vel_y: 0.0  # diff drive robot

  max_trans_vel: 0.3 # choose slightly less than the base's capability
  min_trans_vel: 0.04  # this is the min trans velocity when there is negligible rotational velocity
  trans_stopped_vel: 0.1

  max_rot_vel: 1.57 # default 5.0  # choose slightly less than the base's capability
  min_rot_vel: 0.4  # this is the min angular velocity when there is negligible translational velocity
  rot_stopped_vel: 0.4

  acc_lim_x: 1.0 # maximum is theoretically 2.0, but we 
  acc_lim_theta: 2.0
  acc_lim_y: 0.0      # diff drive robot

 # Goal Tolerance Parameters


 yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.05  # 0.05
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05 # 0.10
  # latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

# Forward Simulation Parameters
  sim_time: 1.7  #1.5       # 1.7
  vx_samples: 20      # 3
  vy_samples: 1   #1       # diff drive robot, there is only one sample
  vtheta_samples: 40  # 20

# Trajectory Scoring Parameters
  path_distance_bias: 32.0      # 32.0   - weighting for how much it should stick to the global path plan
  goal_distance_bias: 12.0      # 24.0   - wighting for how much it should attempt to reach its goal
  occdist_scale: 0.02           # 0.01   - weighting for how much the controller should avoid obstacles
  forward_point_distance: 0.325 #0.325 # 0.325  - how far along to place an additional scoring point
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2         # 0.2    - amount of time a robot must stop in before colliding for a valid traj.
  scaling_speed: 0.25           # 0.25   - absolute velocity at which to start scaling the robot's footprint
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2       # 0.2    - how much to scale the robot's footprint when at speed.

# Oscillation Prevention Parameters
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05  # 0.05   - how far to travel before resetting oscillation flags

# Debugging
  publish_traj_pc : true
  publish_cost_grid_pc: true
  global_frame_id: odom
# Differential-drive robot configuration - necessary?
  holonomic_robot: false
```

Very looking forward anyone can give me any advice to solve this problem! Thank you!

**EDIT1:**

Thank you! @David Lu  I have updated the image with colored cost cloud. The trajectory cloud is not displayed because its topic output nothing suddenly. The topic of trajectory cloud output colored fan-shaped cloud in front of robot normally. However, as the robot cannot move forward, the fan-shaped cloud disappeared.  I am not sure that the topic of cost cloud output normally because it has persistence in rviz. It is not updated until a new message arrives.

**EDIT2:**
Thanks again! @David Lu I did some experiments as you advice. According to the source code of [dwa_local_planner](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/dwa_local_planner/src/dwa_planner.cpp#L168),  there are six cost functions in total. The criteria of these cost functions are pushed into  std::vector<base_local_planner::TrajectoryCostFunction*> critics.
The summary are as follows:

if the three parameters (path_distance_bias, goal_distance_bias, occdist_scale) are all zero, the robot doesn't move. The debug information from base_local_planner is

```
[DEBUG] [1518406865.911248289, 682.570000000]: Evaluated 769 trajectories, found 769 valid 
[DEBUG] [1518406865.917767600, 682.570000000]: Cost PointCloud published
```

if the three parameters are kept unchanged, the robot doesn't move. The debug information from base_local_planner is

```
[DEBUG] [1518396321.802246154, 1539.790000000]: Velocity 0.284, 0.000, 1.000 discarded by cost function  5 with cost: -2.000000
[DEBUG] [1518396321.802506417, 1539.790000000]: Velocity 0.300, 0.000, -1.000 discarded by cost function  5 with cost: -2.00000
```

Which means the goal cost function(goal_costs_) outputs negative value.

if path_distance_bias is set to be zero only, other two parameters are kept unchanged, the robot doesn't move. The debug information is

```
[DEBUG] [1518411651.529508502, 662.150000000]: Velocity 0.142, 0.000, 1.000 discarded by cost function  3 with cost: -2.000000
[DEBUG] [1518411651.530015908, 662.150000000]: Velocity 0.158, 0.000, -1.000 discarded by cost function  3 with cost: -2.00000
```

which means the alignment_costs_ function outputs negative value.

if  occdist_scale is set to be zero only, other two parameters are kept unchanged, the robot  doesn't move. The debug information is

```
Velocity 0.1420, 0.000, 1.000 discarded by cost function  4 with cost: -2.000000
Velocity 0.1580, 0.000, -1.000 discarded by cost function  4 with cost: -2.000000
```

which means the path_costs_ function outputs negative value.

if goal_distance_bias is set to be zero only, other two parameters are kept unchanged, the robot moves normally.

**EDIT3**
Hi, @David Lu,  Following images are goal_cost, occ_cost, path_cost, x, y, z, repectively. The toal cost channel is displayed above.
[image: goal_cost]

[image: occ_cost]

[image: path_cost]

[image: x]

[image: y]

[image: z]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280648/dwa-failed-to-produce-path-in-free-space/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-01-30**:
Is the screenshot showing the local or global costmap?

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2018-01-30**:
Thank you for your attention! It's global costmap. The local costmap is not being shown there. But I don't think this problem is relative to the costmap.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-01-30**:
If there was an obstacle, it would be on the local costmap.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2018-01-30**:
Thank you! The environment of this experiment is in control,  we are sure that there is no obstacle around the robot at that time.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2018-01-31**:
We found that the path.cost_  is smaller than zero which makes the dwa planner can't generate controlling velocity .

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-02-05**:
I would show the local costmap anyway. The most probable reasons for a negative score are obstacles and being off the costmap. It may also help to visualize the cost and trajectory clouds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try systematically setting the weights (`path_distance_bias, goal_distance_bias, occdist_scale`) to zero to see which Cost Function is creating the negative score.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2018-02-12**:
Hi,  I updated the question with "EDIT2". Please give me help again.Thanks!

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2018-02-13**:
Hi, @David LU,  Even though the robot can move by aduusting the parameters at that position, the robot may not move normally at other positions with same parameters. So would you like to tell us how to make the robot always move normally with same parameter setting. Thanks!

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-02-14**:
With all of the parameters non-zero (i.e. their original values) can you  visualize the cost cloud and post screenshots of the different channels of that visualization?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-02**:
There's something wrong with the goal_cost, but then I noticed that the goal seems to be inside an obstacle. Does navigation work if the goal is in free space?